# GraphQL - Categories with entries

Tags: categories, graphql

Is it possible to get categories with related entries with one graphQL query?

I have the following query:

```
query MyQuery {
  categories(relatedToEntries: {section: "entryType"}) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

Giving me this result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "253",
        "title": "Category One"
      },
      {
        "id": "257",
        "title": "Category Two"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like something like the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "253",
        "title": "Category One",
        "entries": [
           {
              "id": 1,
              "title": "Title"
         }
      },
      {
        "id": "257",
        "title": "Category Two",
        "entries": [
           {
              "id": 1,
              "title": "Title"
         }
    ]
  }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps something like this?

I don't know the structure of your data but this would be my best 'educated guess'.

I renamed the different ID's to make it a little more clear in the response.

```
query MyQuery {
  categories(relatedToEntries: {section: "entryType"}) {
    categoryId: id
    title
    entries(relatedToCategories: categoryId) {
      entryId: id,
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. If i put a similar entries query below categories with an hard-code ID i get results, but it does not produce results or errors when located inside the categories query.

Comment: That would suggest that `categoryId` is not actually passed into the nested entries() query. I'm... not sure why tbh.

Comment: Does not work with an hard-coded ID inside the categories query either.. it looks like GQL is basically ignoring the entire entries() query when inside categories()

Comment: I'm starting to wonder how your GraphQL is set up. I think you need to start there and look it over. Following the the docs over at https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html, my solution looks correct.